# Самовыполняющиеся функции

Tags: javascript

Зачем оборачивать блоки кода на JS в самовыполняющиеся функции?

Comment: Пример приведите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Чтобы переменные оставались внутри функции и не захламляли внешний scope: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zy88k0fe/).

Comment: @VladD всё-таки хотелось бы получить пример от автора, чтобы быть уверенным, что речь вообще именно об этом. Надо было эту оговорку в комментарий свой предыдущий добавить.

Comment: @Regent: Ну, вроде бы самовыполняющаяся функция — устоявшийся термин.

Comment: И тема об областях видимости важна, т. к. одно из фундаментальных отличий js от других языков.

Comment: А пример чего вы хотите получить? Самовыполняющейся функции?

Comment: Такой вопрос у меня был в домашнем задании. Примера нет. И информацию найти не получается.

Comment: @GavrenkoKaterina: Вопрос на самом деле касается одного из основополагающих принципов javascript.

Comment: @VladD я скромный (немногим более развёрнутый, чем в комментарии) ответ почти написал, но вот полный и развёрнутый ответ по поводу замыканий и областей видимости вряд ли потяну.

Comment: Гуглите IIFE ;)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228281/what-is-the-function-construct-in-javascript

Comment: @Regent запостите, а потом правками улучшите. Или запостите как вики, тогда и другие дополнят

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Переменные, объявленные внутри функции, являются локальными (находятся в её области видимости). Это даёт как минимум 3 полезных момента:

1. "Снаружи" не "достучаться" до того, что объявлено внутри функции.
2. Не получится случайно затереть глобальную переменную, объявив переменную с таким же именем внутри функции.
3. Глобальная область видимости не "захламляется" данными, которые не должны быть глобальными.

Самовыполняющаяся функция (Immediately-Invoked Function Expression, IIFE) позволяет воспользоваться этими преимуществами, не создавая глобальную функцию.

```js
var x = 1;
(function() {
    var x = 2;
    var y = 3;
    console.log("In: " + x); //In: 2
    console.log("In: " + y); //In: 3
})();
console.log("Out: " + x); //Out: 1
console.log("Out: " + y); //ReferenceError: y is not defined
```

Например, можно использовать самовыполняющуюся функции для того, чтобы сохранять данные, необходимые для работы функции, и которые при этом нужно хранить между вызовами функции:

```js
var test = (function() {
    var count = 0;
    return function() {
        count++;
        console.log("Count: " + count);
    };
})();
test(); //Count: 1
test(); //Count: 2
console.log(count); //ReferenceError: count is not defined
```

Переменная `count` недоступна в глобальной области видимости, однако доступна внутри возвращаемой функции, так как та объявлена внутри самовыполняющейся функции, и поэтому имеет доступ к её области видимости.

---

Также самовыполняющаяся функция может "помочь" с сохранением промежуточных значений данных при асинхронном выполнении кода.

Например:

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log(i);
    }, 1000 * i);
}
```

Данный код будет выводить в консоль раз в секунду не числа по возрастанию, а число `10`, потому что на момент вызова первой функции в `setTimeout` глобальная переменная `i` уже будет равна `10` (сначала проходят все итерации цикла, а уже потом вызывается первая функция).

Если же обернуть `setTimeout` в функцию и передавать ей `i` в качестве аргумента, то вывод будет от `0` до `9`:

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    (function(i) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log(i);
        }, 1000 * i);
    })(i);
}
```

В данном случае переменная `i` в `setTimeout` уже не является глобальной переменной и не зависит от её изменений. Однако тут не нужно забывать о том, что если переменная является объектом, то изменение значения поля объекта "снаружи" приведёт и к изменению значения поля объекта "внутри".