# Зациклить код javasccript

Tags: javascript, оптимизация

Привет, есть код:

```
$('#k0').click(function(){var z0=$('#c0').val();if ($("#c0:checked").length == 0) {$('#c0').prop("checked", true);var a=z0;$("#k0").css({'opacity':'0.1'});} else {var a="off";$('#c0').prop("checked", false);$("#k0").css({'opacity':'1'});}});
$('#k1').click(function(){var z1=$('#c1').val();if ($("#c1:checked").length == 0) {$('#c1').prop("checked", true);var a=z1;$("#k1").css({'opacity':'0.1'});} else {var a="off";$('#c1').prop("checked", false);$("#k1").css({'opacity':'1'});}});
$('#k2').click(function(){var z2=$('#c2').val();if ($("#c2:checked").length == 0) {$('#c2').prop("checked", true);var a=z2;$("#k2").css({'opacity':'0.1'});} else {var a="off";$('#c2').prop("checked", false);$("#k2").css({'opacity':'1'});}});
$('#k3').click(function(){var z3=$('#c3').val();if ($("#c3:checked").length == 0) {$('#c3').prop("checked", true);var a=z3;$("#k3").css({'opacity':'0.1'});} else {var a="off";$('#c3').prop("checked", false);$("#k3").css({'opacity':'1'});}});
$('#k4').click(function(){var z4=$('#c4').val();if ($("#c4:checked").length == 0) {$('#c4').prop("checked", true);var a=z4;$("#k4").css({'opacity':'0.1'});} else {var a="off";$('#c4').prop("checked", false);$("#k4").css({'opacity':'1'});}});
```

Пробовал его  укоротить... Что-то не получается.. Подскажте где ошибка?

```
var i = 0;
while (i < 4) {
$('#k' + i).click(function(){
    var 'z' + i = $('#c' + i).val();
    if ($("#c" + i + ":checked").length == 0) {
        $('#c' + i).prop("checked", true);
        var a = 'z' + i;
        $("#k" + i).css({'opacity':'0.1'});
    } else {
        var a = "off";
        $('#c' + i).prop("checked", false);
        $("#k" + i).css({'opacity':'1'});
    }
});
i++;
}
```

И можно ли сокртить такое?

```
if ($('form input:checked#c0').val()) {
cards["0"] = 'on';
}

if ($('form input:checked#c1').val()) {
cards["1"] = 'on';
}

if ($('form input:checked#c2').val()) {
cards["2"] = 'on';
}

if ($('form input:checked#c3').val()) {
cards["3"] = 'on';
}

if ($('form input:checked#c4').val()) {
 cards["4"] = 'on';
}
```

Comment: Если вы вызываете один и тот же обработчик для разных элементов, пора задуматься о том, чтобы добавить к этим элементом имя класса и выбирать эти элементы по классу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если присмотреться, функции практически ничем не отличаются, кроме значения id, которое можно взять из элемента по которому кликнули. Плюсом объявлено несколько переменных, значения которых нигде не используются.

```
$('#k1').click(function() {
  var z1 = $('#c1').val(); // не используется
  if ($("#c1:checked").length == 0) {
    $('#c1').prop("checked", true);
    var a = z1;// не используется
    $("#k1").css({
      'opacity': '0.1'
    });
  } else {
    var a = "off"; // не используется
    $('#c1').prop("checked", false);
    $("#k1").css({
      'opacity': '1'
    });
  }
});
```

Ошибка вашего подхода в том, что функции создаваемые во время цикла - захватывают переменную `i` - значение которой будет проверять **только** во время выполнения функции. Дли исправления можно применять [IIFE(самовызывающиеся функциональные выражения)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/471102/%D0%A1%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8)

Но, так как навешивание обработчиков событий в jQuery может применяться к нескольким выбранным элементам (цикл уже есть внутри), то достаточно собрать нужные id в селектор и добавить к нему обработчик *click*.

В итоге все можно сократить до

```
$('#k0,#k1,#k2,#k3,#k4').click(function() {
  var $this = $(this),
      id = $this.attr('id'), // #k0..5
      idNum = id.replace(/\D/g,''), //0..5
      $c = $('#c'+id),
      $k = $('#k'+id);

  $c.prop('checked', !$c.prop('checked'));
  $k.css({
      'opacity': $c.prop('checked') ? '0.1' : '1'
    });
});
```

При этом динамически собирать нужно/можно только селектор:

```
'#k0,#k1,#k2,#k3,#k4'
```

например:

```
new Array(5).join().split(',').map(function(_, index){ 
    return '#k'+index
}).join(); // "#k0,#k1,#k2,#k3,#k4"
```

---

По поводу кода

```
if ($('form input:checked#c0').val()) {
    cards["0"] = 'on';
}

if ($('form input:checked#c1').val()) {
    cards["1"] = 'on';
}

if ($('form input:checked#c2').val()) {
    cards["2"] = 'on';
}

if ($('form input:checked#c3').val()) {
    cards["3"] = 'on';
}

if ($('form input:checked#c4').val()) {
    cards["4"] = 'on';
}
```

Конечно это можно сократить, так как опять используется повтор кода

```
$('form input:checked').each(function(){ //бежим в цикле по выбранным чекбоксам
    var $this = $(this),//получаем jQuery объект для текущего проверяемого элемента    
        id = $this.attr('id').replace(/\D/g,'');// получаем цифры из id
    if($this.val()){ //проверяем значение
        cards[id] = 'on'; // выставляем нужный элемент в массиве
    }
});
```

Comment: Спасибо. Второй код использовал. Трудновато для моего понимания пока что javascript

Comment: @Алекс, второй это какой? :) _Трудновато для моего понимания пока что javascript_ - а я-то думал что подробно расписал.